# Making a Python unit test that never runs in parallel

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

**tl;dr -** I want to write a Python `unittest` function that deletes a file, runs a test, and the restores the file. This causes race conditions because `unittest` runs multiple tests in parallel, and deleting and creating the file for one test messes up other tests that happen at the same time.

**Long Specific Example:**

I have a Python module named `converter.py` and it has associated tests in `test_converter.py`. If there is a file named `config_custom.csv` in the same directory as `converter.py`, then the custom configuration will be used. If there is no custom CSV config file, then there is a default configuration built into `converter.py`.

I wrote a unit test using `unittest` from the Python 2.7 standard library to validate this behavior. The unit test in `setUp()` would rename `config_custom.csv` to `wrong_name.csv`, then it would run the tests (hopefully using the default config), then in `tearDown()` it would rename the file back the way it should be.

**Problem:** Python unit tests run in parallel, and I got terrible race conditions. The file `config_custom.csv` would get renamed in the middle of other unit tests in a non-deterministic way. It would cause at least one error or failure about 90% of the time that I ran the entire test suite.

The ideal solution would be to tell `unittest`: **Do NOT** run this test in parallel with other tests, this test is special and needs complete isolation.

My work-around is to add an optional argument to the function that searches for config files. The argument is only passed by the test suite. It ignores the config file without deleting it. Actually deleting the test file is more graceful, that is what I actually want to test.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently need to run tests with complete isolation. The only way I've found that works consistently is to put those tests in separate classes. Agreed that handling config files inside tests is still kind of a pain.

For something I'm doing right now, I may also try something like [pytest-ordering](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) for running tests in a more deterministic fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The Django 3.2 documentation contains an official solution to this problem using the `django.test.testcases.SerializeMixin`. This will force certain tests to run in series and prevent errors arising when they try to access the same resource.

As per  the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/advanced/#enforce-running-test-classes-sequentially), you would do something like this:

```
import os

from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.testcases import SerializeMixin

class ImageTestCaseMixin(SerializeMixin):
    lockfile = __file__

    def setUp(self):
        self.filename = os.path.join(temp_storage_dir, 'my_file.png')
        self.file = create_file(self.filename)

class RemoveImageTests(ImageTestCaseMixin, TestCase):
    def test_remove_image(self):
        os.remove(self.filename)
        self.assertFalse(os.path.exists(self.filename))

class ResizeImageTests(ImageTestCaseMixin, TestCase):
    def test_resize_image(self):
        resize_image(self.file, (48, 48))
        self.assertEqual(get_image_size(self.file), (48, 48))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly most testing framework that support parallelism also support methods to serial certain important tests. For instance Python [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/parallel.html) support a serial annotation (when you launch your test as a parallel suite with command line flag -P):

```
from fabric.api import *

def runs_in_parallel():
    pass

@serial
def runs_serially():
    pass
```

---

However, I don't think you should do that, I think you should stop and contempt for a moment. Following the [Single Responsibility Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) this is what I would say is going on.

You are in a situation where a test has essentially identified a condition of your code, it's highlight a little spot of cohesion for you.

What you should do now is realise that "converter.py" has too many responsibilities, not only does it perform some complex operation under the hood it is also responsibility for managing it's own creation and set-up in a way that is probably too much for it.

Perhaps if you had an object that can management reading in that file, you could then easily mock/stub it out and produce the condition you are describing that you want to test.

Comment: I am aware of Fabric, but I didn't know the `@serial` decorator, so thank you. Regarding the Single Responsibility Principle: I feel that I already adhere to it well. `converter.py` is just one file, but it has multiple functions (not too many). One of the functions is `load_config()`, and it has just one responsibility. Iff it finds a config file, it loads it, otherwise it uses the defaults. It actually doesn't need any arguments, but I added `load_config(use_defaults=False)` and pass in `True` ONLY during unit tests, which is what you suggested. This is suboptimal.

Comment: (Part 2 of 2) Using a kwarg like this has two problems: First, the source code of `converter.py` just became more complex. I just added a feature to `converter.py` that nobody should ever use, only unit tests should use it. That is the definition of something that belongs with the tests, not the code itself. Second: What if all the tests pass using this fake-out, but *actually* not finding a file causes a hard crash? The unit tests cannot see this problem anymore. The unit tests will pass. If `os.listdir()` changes and there is a regression, I will not see it.

Comment: Yup, I would concur with you points there. Answered this question a long old time ago and would have different ideas about things at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The best testing strategy would be to make sure your testing on disjoint data sets. This will bypass any race conditions and make the code simpler. I would also mock out `open` or `__enter__` / `__exit__` if your using the context manager. This will allow you to fake the event that a file doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the name of `config_custom.csv` should itself be a configurable parameter. Then each test can simply look for `config_custom_<nonce>.csv`, and any number of tests may be run in parallel.

Cleanup of the overall suite can just clear out `config_custom_*.csv`, since we won't be needing any of them at that point.

Comment: The file name actually is configurable. I really want to test the behavior if nothing is found. My work-around, mentioned in my original question, is fundamentally similar to this suggestion, and it doesn't actually test the behavior I want. My work around is to tell the config-file-finder "do not look for any config files". You suggestion is basically "only look for specific config files". I want to test the behavior if it looks normally and finds nothing. I do not want to turn off or limit the search itself.

Comment: @SerMetAla Using distinct files is a good way to do it without introducing locking. If you can't use distinct sets of files then you should just use locks.